# Manga with a boy reincarnated and gifted an item-box filled with overpowered items

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story is about a boy who gets reincarnated into another world. The Goddess gives him an item box full of overpowered items like high level healing potions, mythril armor and swords, etc.

When he tries to enter a city a guard sees his high level armour and tries to rob him of all his money because he thinks the protagonist is a noble and because the main character is relatively young.

When I read this it only had 3-4 chapters and seemed very short. I'm hoping it has more chapters now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By_the_Grace_of_the_Gods?

Comment: @Valorum not that one

Comment: This question is very terse (and generic) and could be greatly improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the main character's name? Did he come from modern-day Japan? How did he get there? Was he reincarnated as a baby or as a young person? What did he look like? How did he access his item box? What goddess was supporting him? What did she look like? Was this an adult manga (with sex/nudity/gore) or something aimed at general audiences? Was this in colour or black-and-white? Was there a love-interest? What did his item-box look like (e.g. a menu screen or a literal box)? Did he have other powers? Was this a world with magic? What did his parents do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

It was [Isekai Wa Template Ni Michiafurete Iru (Another World Is Full of Happiness)](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/dpxxbu9/isekai-wa-template-ni-michiafurete-iru-comic).

> Ryoji (26-year-old man), who was hopeless due to a broken heart,
> One day, the goddess I met at the roadside flew into another world as a boy.
> There are plenty of template events I read in my favorite web novel!
> By making full use of the cheat ability that I ordered with the Goddess even finely, both swords and magic are great!
> And the receptionist and adventurer who met in the guild to the group,
> Enjoy the event as if you were the protagonist of the story.
>
> [image]